# What is the difference between admit and accept in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning, vocabulary

My heart does not admit what my mind already knows

My heart does not accept what my mind already knows

Answer (score 1):

There is little or no difference in this context.

Usually **accept** has a sense close to "agree", while **admit** has a sense of "confess", "concede", "accept reluctantly" (although "admit" can also mean "formally allow [to enter or attend or join]").

However, in your sentences, in context, the difference is minimal.  Both sentences express the heart's refusal or inability to agree with something the mind already knows to be true.

Normally, one can agree with or accept a statement without admitting it.  One might privately accept a truth but refuse to admit it publicly.  However, in your example, this distinction between admission and acceptance is meaningless because both sentences make clear that the true situation is known to the mind.  Both express the idea that the heart is struggling against the truth and that the heart rejects or refuses to acknowledge that truth.